# Exponential formula in the derivation of the Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question on this [prior post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/385427/520393) on the derivation of the normal distribution.

The author had set up the target/dart analogy often used to introduce a translation-invariant bivariate, uncorrelated distribution $f(x,y) = g(x^2 + y^2),$ which ends up helping in the integration through the use of the Pythagoras theorem and change to polar coordinates.

At that point he mentions:

> This means that $g$ must be an exponential function
>
> $g(t) = A e^{-Bt}$

based on the independence of $X$ and $Y.$

This seemingly obvious step is not clear to me, and would like to ask why this is so clear - intuitively, yes, assuming a plausible competent dart thrower, the majority of darts will group around the center of the target, and there'll be an exponential drop-off away from the center (perhaps more or less rapid depending on the accuracy of the thrower).

But I don't see it mathematically.

---

Comment: It is a property of the exponential function that it is a solution to the equation $$g(x+y) = g(x)g(y).$$ Many calculus textbooks cover this result.  The result in question is _not_ based on the independence of $X$ and $Y$ but rather on the point that $g(x^2+y^2)\proportionalto g(x^2)g(y^2)$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Got it! $g(x^2) = e^{x^2}$ because $e^{x^2+y^2}=e^{x^2}e^{y^2}.$ Very close to the [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function): $ae^{-(x-b)^2/2c^2}.$ Thank you!

Comment: @DilipSarwate In MathJax, use `\propto` for $\propto$